# Rvalue reference parameters and template functions

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

If I define a function which accepts an rvalue reference parameter:

```
template <typename T>
void fooT(T &&x) {}
```

I can call it, using GCC 4.5, with either `a`, `ar`, or `arr`:

```
int a, &ar = a, &&arr = 7;
fooT(a); fooT(ar); fooT(arr);
```

However, calling a similar, *non-template* function,

```
void fooInt(int &&x) {}
```

with any of those three arguments will fail. I was preparing to strengthen my knowledge of `forward`, but this has knocked me off course. Perhaps it's GCC 4.5; I was surprised to find that the first example from [A Brief Introduction to Rvalue References](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/rvalue.html) also gives a compile error:

```
A a;
A&& a_ref2 = a;  // an rvalue reference
```

Comment: The correct way to make the example work is to explicitly* make it an rvalue, with: `A&& a_ref2 = std::move(a)`. *Explicit is a good thing, so you don't accidentally move stuff around.

Comment: [Scott Meyers' explanation](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11).  This is now called a *Universal Reference*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The behavior of deduction in template parameters is unique, and is the reason your template version works. I've explained exactly how this deduction works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward/3582313#3582313), in the context of another question.

Summarized: when the argument is an lvalue, `T` is deduced to `T&`, and `T& &&` collapses to `T&`. And with the parameter at `T&`, it is perfectly valid to supply an lvalue `T` to it. Otherwise, `T` remains `T`, and the parameter is `T&&`, which accepts rvalues arguments.

Contrarily, `int&&` is always `int&&` (no template deduction rules to coerce it to something else), and can only bind to rvalues.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to GMan's correct answer [A Brief Introduction to Rvalue References](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/rvalue.html) has an incorrect example because it was written prior to a language change which outlawed:

```
A a;
A&& a_ref2 = a;  // an rvalue reference (DISALLOWED in C++11)
```

Despite this change in the language, the main uses cases described in the article (move and forward) are still explained correctly in the article.

Update:  Oh, and the same article was originally published [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2027.html) with (imho) slightly better formatting.