# Why is it possible to pass an lvalue to `std::async` even though it takes an rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, rvalue, lvalue

The function `std::async` is defined like so:

```
template< class Function, class... Args>
std::future<std::result_of_t<std::decay_t<Function>(std::decay_t<Args>...)>>
    async( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

As we can see, it takes both arguments as rvalue-references, or more precisely, as "universal references" (rvalue references to the template argument types).

Passing a simple function pointer (e.g. `std::async(myfunction)`) works, and I don't understand why.

My understanding is that you can bind an rvalue to a const lvalue reference - but not vice versa. You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference (without casting it to an rvalue using `std::move`).

However - when calling `std::async(myfunction)`, the `std::async` template is instantiated with `Function = <some_func_type>`, and so becomes `std::async<some_func_type>(some_func_type&&)`. That is - it takes an rvalue reference. However, we pass it an lvalue.

Why does it work?

Comment: universal references are not r-value references, thats how they got their name

Comment: the official name is forwarding reference btw

Comment: @idclev463035818 Indeed, but if I understand correctly, the universal reference `Function&&` because `Thing&&` when `Function = Thing`. Correct?

Comment: Note that when `T = int &`, then `T && = int &` (not `int &&`) since, roughly speaking a reference-to-reference is simplified to just reference, and the result is an rvalue reference only in the case "rvalue-reference to rvalue-reference", and is an lvalue reference in all other three cases. Informally, the collapsing rules are `& = & & = && & = & &&` and `&& && = &&`. Hence a type of the form `T &&` can be any kind of reference, rvalue or lvalue, and not just rvalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As we can see, it takes both arguments as rvalue-references, or more precisely, as "universal references" (rvalue references to the template argument types).

The term "universal reference" (or "forwarding reference") is not a *more precise* term for rvalue references. It's a different thing.

When you put `&&` on a template parameter type like that, it's a forwarding reference. These will bind to lvalues, by design.

**tl;dr: It's *not* an rvalue reference.**

<sup>*(Okay, it kind of is, but [deduction and reference-collapsing rules make it *effectively* not one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5532574/4386278), so we don't call it one. Hence the special name for this case: "forwarding reference".)*</sup>